# Reading large csv files

Tags: vb.net, file, csv

Which is the most performant way to read a large csv file in .NET?
Using FileStream? or another class?
Thanks!

Comment: I sincerely hope you are [not rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read it all into memory, a simple `File.ReadAllText()` will do just fine.

**EDIT:** If your file is indeed very large, then you can use the `StreamReader` class, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) for details. This approach is sometimes inevitable but should mostly be avoided for style reasons. See [here](http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2007/11/please-use-filereadalltext-and-like.html) for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: yes but if the file is large, it's probably better to read it line by line

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) returned by [`FileInfo.OpenText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext.aspx):

```
Dim file As New FileInfo("path\to\file")

Using reader As StreamReader = file.OpenText()
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim nextLine As String = reader.ReadLine()
        ProcessCsvLine(nextLine)
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of doing this is by taking advantage of deffered execution in LINQ. You can create a simple Linq-To-Text function that read one line at a time, work on it and then continue. This is really helpful since the file is really large.

I would desist from using the ReadBlock or ReadBlock or ReadToEnd methods of StreamReader class since they tend to read a number of lines at once or even the entire lines in the file. This ends up consuming more memory than if a line was read one at a time.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Lines(this StreamReader source)
{
    String line;

    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Note that the function is an extension method of the StreamReader class. This means it can be used as follows:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("TextFile.txt"))
       {
            var tokens = from line in streamReader.Lines()
            let items = line.Split(',')               
            select String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                items[1].PadRight(16),
                items[2].PadRight(16),
                items[3].PadRight(16));

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of ceremony when you could simply use `While (line = streamReader.ReadLine() != null)` in your second code block.

Answer (score 1):

I had very good experience with this library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library for Csv reading. This is really nice to use

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F